# Which is the proper grip for dumbbell biceps curl?

Tags: weightlifting, workout, bodybuilding, powerlifting, biceps

is it better for dumbbell biceps curl:

- **a high palm grip** (such as that of deadlift)

[image]

- **a bulldog low palm grip** (such as that of bench press and overhead press)

[image]

- **a traditional low palm grip**

[image]

My opinion: bulldog grip is not necessary since our forearm is above the weight. But, I can't say which grip is better and why. A high palm grip is known to be the best one if you want to trap too much skin and have pain.

Comment: I think this will be opinion-based. My favourite grip is thumbless, so.

Comment: Best grip is usually the one you feel most comfortable with and the one that allows you to move most weight without pain etc. (unless you're doing deadlifts or Olympic lifting where hook grip is recommended).

Comment: "The proper grip" for what ? More Strenght? more endurance?

Comment: @Liiuc safety and hand comfort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why searching for THE proper grip? Why not actually taking advantage of variations?

What do you think is best for overall performance? Running at the same pace always or having some slow days, some fast days and then everything in between?

It’s the same for grip. Vary your grip. You can actually read in Arnold Schwarzenegger's bodybuilding bible how he used some very specific grips to target some very specific development in his body.